# Suhosin and disable eval function

Tags: php, suhosin

I have installed Suhosin on my dedicated CentOS server. `centos6.7+php5.4.41+suhosin0.9.36`

I would like to enable Suhosin's disable eval function.
I went through the documentation and from what I understood, the best scenario was to add this in php.ini:

```
[suhosin]
suhosin.executor.eval.blacklist= phpinfo,passthru,exec,system,chroot,scandir,chgrp,chown
```

but it will not prevent eval from executing phpinfo(),`<?php eval(phpinfo());?>`.

Really hoping someone can point out my  mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example executes phpinfo(), then tries to evaluate the output. Given your configuration the following example will be blocked by suhosin:

`eval("phpinfo();");`

Please consider using whitelisting as opposed to blacklisting, if applicable. From a security point of view it is always best to allow a limited set of functions rather than guess all the bad functions.

Also note, that eval itself is not a function and cannot be blocked by disable_functions and friends. Suhosin provides `suhosin.executor.disable_eval` for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Open the `php.ini` file and look for `disable_functions`. Write/Enlist the functions which you want to disable. For example: `disable_functions=passthru,exec,system,popen,eval`

Comment: i want to  disable eval functions,do not disable functions